# Проблема с авторизацией Yii

Tags: yii2

Здравствуйте! На Easyii CMS (Yii2) поставил плагин dektrium/yii2-user
После логина ошибка:

```
 Class name must be a valid object or a string
 in vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/User.php
```

Код из файла User.php :

```
     {
      $session = Yii::$app->getSession();
      $id = $session->getHasSessionId() || $session->getIsActive() ?     
     $session->get($this->idParam) : null;

    if ($id === null) {
        $identity = null;
    } else {
        /* @var $class IdentityInterface */
        $class = $this->identityClass;
        $identity = $class::findIdentity($id);
    }

    $this->setIdentity($identity);

    if ($identity !== null && ($this->authTimeout !== null || $this->absoluteAuthTimeout !== null)) {
        $expire = $this->authTimeout !== null ? $session->get($this->authTimeoutParam) : null;
        $expireAbsolute = $this->absoluteAuthTimeout !== null ? $session->get($this->absoluteAuthTimeoutParam) : null;
        if ($expire !== null && $expire < time() || $expireAbsolute !== null && $expireAbsolute < time()) {
            $this->logout(false);
```

Ошибка в строке:

```
 $this->setIdentity($identity);
```

В чем может быть проблема? Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Вероятнее всего ошибка не в указанном вами файле. Проблема в самом объекте, который возвращает `$class::findIdentity($id);`

Проверьте что бы ваша реализация метода `findIdentity` в модели "пользователя" возвращала валидный объект. Пример реализации данного метода:

```
public static function findIdentity($id)
{
    return static::findOne(['id' => $id, 'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE]);
}
```

Так же, если вы пользовались миграциями из данного модуля, проверьте есть ли пользователь в таблице `user`так как модуль, по умолчанию использует свои таблица для работы.